# Mediation package in R output

Tags: r, mediation

The mediation package in R returns results in which:

- ACME = significant (positive)
- ADE = significant (positive)
- Total Effects = significant(positive)

---

Does this mean that there is a full mediation effect or partial?

Answer (score 1):

This means there is partial mediation. If there is a nonzero direct effect (ADE), the effect of the main predictor does not pass entirely through the mediator.